# Drawing graphics for LCDs

Tags: python, drawing

Im not sure if this is the correct place to ask this but as its more programming related than electronics I am posting here.

I have recently purchased a small LCD to experiment with. Its just one colour. Im using python to control it over serial.

My question is when it comes to the actual drawing. This whole area is completely new to me so I don't know if I am thinking the right way / going down the right path.

I want to be able to draw things on the LCD such as progress bars, animations (such as volume meters etc) and other simple - non text - based things. Just anything really.

In my mind the way I imagine doing this is by using python to draw a complete image of what I want on the LCD. Using PIL / Pillow for example and constantly redrawing and resending to the LCD.
So in the case of the progress bar, everything that's static is the same but then the progress bar rectangle for example would have its width altered each redraw.

I dont know if this it the correct way or if there are better ways or even if there are specific tools / modules for this kind of thing.

Comment: What kind of an interface do you have to the LCD? I mean; OK, serial communication (RS232 over USB, maybe?), but what is the protocol you talk over this connection? Do you have a link to a manual or a product page for the specific LCD?

Comment: you likely need to write a command string of some type to the LCD ... what LCD is it? and how are you hooked up to it?

Comment: The communication is not a problem. I can already draw on the LCD. It uses I2C. The question is more on the general way to draw a animation / display etc. Its controlled at the pixel level

Comment: The communication might not be a problem, but it is definitely relevant information. Do you update the entire screen for every frame? Is there even enough bandwidth to do this? Can the microcontroller keep up? Or do you send commands to do partial updates? If you can do full screen redraws every frame, this question is reduced to how to generate graphics in an in-memory buffer -- a much simpler question! :)

Comment: Ah I see . the controller IC is the SSD1306 chip.

Comment: Thanks :) That's a bit too much for me to go through right now. I think it might be helpful if you could more clearly detail what you have been successful at, and exactly which problems are stopping you :)

Comment: OK basically I can draw to the LCD no problem. Using some example code and tutorials. Making an image with PIL and then writing the data pixel by pixel to the LCD. But now I want to do a bit more such as progress bars, animations such as a sound Meter etc, I don't know if this is the best method still.